# Red5: installing demos

Tags: red5

I have installed red5 & started it . But when I try to install demos (http://localhost:5080/installer/), it shows `connecting...` and never ends.

I have a good internet connection. What is the problem?

I have installed the latest: `Red5-1.0.0-RC2.exe` and jdk version 7: `jdk-7u7-windows-i586.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You might check if the repository the demos are loaded from is online or not.
Have you checked the URL of the demo repository?

Comment: How can i check it ? please tell me . can i stream from my pc to internet using red5 ?

Comment: You don't need JDK in order to run Red5, JRE is sufficient. You can see all source code of the demo application client side code at: https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fflash%2Ftrunk

Comment: Or maybe those ones are better: https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fjava%2Fexample%2Ftrunk